# Best platform for public events web site?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, drupal, programming-languages

Greetings all - I would very grateful for your professional opinions on the "best" (most appropriate) development platform for creating a public/social events web site.  Since "best" too vague, let me be more specific!

My goal is to create a web-based business (a basic web site) that lets people post and search for local events in their local area.  Great examples of what I want to create are http://www.localwineevents.com and http://templatic.com/cms-themes/events  I plan to make money by selling ad space and having people pay to post "premium" events.

I have a detailed web site specifications doc (mind you, I'm not a programmer).  But before I post a project on Guru or RentACoder, I want to be sure I understand what type of programming platform (and programmer) I should look for.

My current thinking is Wordpress because it seems like a lot of the functionality I want is already available via plugins.

But since I know very little about Drupal, RoR, PHP, Java, I want to be sure I pick the most appropriate platform for my needs.  Here are some of the things I want my site to do to help shed more light:

- Registration/login for users
- Facebook/Twitter integration
- Use forms to capture user and event information
- Ability for users to search posted events by zip code (like Yelp)
- PayPal and banner ads integration

I plan to focus on a local geography at first but, once the site is up and running, expand to major US cities.  Scalability will be important and I want a site that is ultimately capable of supporting millions of concurrent users without a complete redesign.

Thoughts???

Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry this site is for programmers. Not to sound negative, but this has been done over and over again to death, for free. Maybe not the best business plan to compete with free. Voting to close.

Comment: Ha! Now that I have your business plan AND knowledge of the web/web programming, I'll build the site tonight and launch it tomorrow!

Comment: " Scalability will be important and I want a site that is ultimately capable of supporting millions of concurrent users without a complete redesign" - that old chestnut!

Comment: You guys crack me up! Guess I deserve those comments. So nothing then on my question?

Comment: By the way, this would be a great question to ask on Quora, as you'll find other entrepreneurs with startup experience who can give good advice.

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't a "best" platform for this site. I think you'll be better off finding a good developer (or team) who's passionate about the site, and uses whatever tool(s) they feel most comfortable with in order to meet your value propositions.

That said, here are some points to consider:

1. Will you need to be able to edit content on the site? This can range from needing to post an announcement to being able to add/edit events / blog posts / etc.  If this is the case, then you need to make sure the developers use a standard CMS. There's no need for them to roll their own CMS, and you definitely don't want to have to rely on them to put this type of content up if it'll be frequent. Those should be warning signs.
2. html, css, and javascript are still kings - These are skills that you'll want to look for regardless of what platform they build the site on. In fact, it's not unheard of to develop the prototype (or clickable design) in pure html/css/javascript to get the look and feel down.
3. What are the sizes of the various developer communities in your area? If you have an active users group for that technology, for example, then whoever you hire will have resources, and you'll be able to find more / replacements as well
4. Of course, how well you work with the developers may end up being more important than the technologies they use (to a point, at least). If this is intended to turn into a long-standing relationship, then find developers who can communicate with you about the product based on your business goals, and who understand your goals and constraints.

Comment: Really helpful input, Ben.  Thanks very much!